# Matlab Plotting the Result of Solving An Equation

Tags: matlab, plot, solver, symbolic-math

I am trying to solve an equation, and then plot the result. Here is my script:

```
>> syms h t 
>> eq = 100*((100+(10-h)^2)/(10-h)) - t - 2000

eq =

- t - (100*((h - 10)^2 + 100))/(h - 10) - 2000

>> solve(eq,h);
>> solve(eq,h)

ans =

   ((t*(t + 4000))/10000)^(1/2)/2 - t/200
 - t/200 - ((t*(t + 4000))/10000)^(1/2)/2

ezplot(((t*(t+4000))/10000)^(1/2)/2-t/200-t/200-((t*(t+4000))/10000)^(1/2)/2)
```

Rather than plot the function

```
((t*(t+4000))/10000)^(1/2)/2-t/200-t/200-((t*(t+4000))/10000)^(1/2)/2
```

it plots the function `-t/100`. Why did it do this? How can I amend this?

Comment: Because it's the same? ;-) Simplify your function and you'll see

Comment: But it should involve a square root function, even after simplification. I was able to get the to work once, but now it is no longer plotting a square root function.

Comment: Oh, I see what I did. I combined both functions into one, not realizing that solve() obtained two distinct roots, as horchler alluded to.

Comment: Yes, I didn't realized that either. I just saw "your" function and well, it does equal `-t/100` :-) +1 for @horchler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not one function wrapped onto two lines. The `solve` function returned two separate solutions to your equation. `eq` is quadratic in `h`, so you might expect there to be two solutions. You can plot each of the solutions like this:

```
s = solve(eq,h);
figure
ezplot(s(1))
figure
ezplot(s(2))
```